# My RedirectToPage is not working in a Razor page

Tags: .net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a Razor page which posts a form and then EF updates a database table. After this process is complete I want to navigate to another page, however my page redirect is not working. The OnPostSubmit method (below) resides in the index page and I want to redirect to the FormComplete page.  Both pages reside in the Pages folder. This is a very simple requirement, but my redirect does not happen. Any ideas to why the redirect does not occur?

```
    public IActionResult OnPostSubmit(FormViewModel model)
    {
        // update logic here

        return RedirectToPage("/FormComplete");
    }
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint inside of `OnPostSubmit` to verify it's being called?

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that the OnPostSubmit is called.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Telerik form component and I was attempting to redirect to a page after submitting the form which was sending an Ajax request. This is not possible so I will redirect using JS from the client side.